# Errors while import-image from a private registry (exactly the gitlab container registry...) on openshift-origin

Tags: certificate, registry, openshift-origin, gitlab-8

According to https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/managing_images.html , I had generated a secret named 'test-secret' by command :

`oc secrets new-dockercfg test-secret \
--docker-server=my.registry.com:5000 \  #if the port '5000' needed? But I get the same error with the two cases 
--docker-username=origin \
--docker-password=XXX \
--docker-email=origin@XXX.com`

then adding the secret to serviceaccount by :

`oc secrets link default test-secret --for=pull`

`oc secrets link builder test-secret`

The certificate of registry 'ca.crt' had been put on 
'/etc/docker/cert.d/registry.example.com:5000/ca.crt' , and I can pull the image by `docker pull registry.example.com:5000/XXX/XXXX:XXX`.

But errors follow while running :

`oc import-image XXX:master --from=registry.example.com:5000/XXX/XXXX --confirm` :

`The import completed with errors.`

`Name:          XXX
Namespace:      XXXX
Created:        20 minutes ago
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:        openshift.io/image.dockerRepositoryCheck=2017-03-31T07:02:41Z
Docker Pull Spec:   172.30.81.113:5000/XXXX/XXX
Unique Images:      0
Tags:           1`

`master
  tagged from registry.XXXX.com:5000/XXX/XXXX`

`! error: Import failed (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Get
https://registry.XXXX.com:5000/v2/XXXX/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden
      20 minutes ago`

And the registry server logs :

`time="2017-03-31T07:49:14.323833338Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: authorization token required" go.version=go1.6.2 http.request.host="registry.example.com:5000" http.request.id=7476c6f4-b563-4132-8912-f0f19a5beb72 http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="192.168.1.23:52540" http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="Go-http-client/1.1" instance.id=0b54b523-31bf-4b56-adcc-e20320f4cea9 service=registry version=v2.4.1 
192.168.1.23 - - [31/Mar/2017:07:49:14 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "" "Go-http-client/1.1"`

Help please !

Answer (score 2):

For gitlab:
Create and link 2 secrets with same credentials, first for  gitlab's docker registry url, second for gitlab url.

Comment: Sure I fixed it with creating two secret files as you said.

Comment: I've added the same set of credentials, one for `registry.gitlab.com` and one for `gitlab.com` and it worked.